# Grid binding in a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am developing a website in which I need to bind a grid several times {inside a for loop}
and as expected the grid overwrites the previous values and preview s the latest iteration result

You may need the code for help.Here it is:-

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
    {
        business.clsplugins obj = new business.clsplugins();
        List<business.clspluginsprp> objprp = new List<business.clspluginsprp>();
        Int32 z = Convert.ToInt32(k.GetValue(i));
        objprp = obj.fnd_plugins(z);
        GridView2.DataSource = objprp;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you need the databind to do?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you want, if you only want to show the result of the latest binding you could call DataBind() only after the last iteration...

Comment: Am I missing the point here? Why would you bind a GridView INSIDE a for loop? The Gridview can only show 1 set at a time, so binding it more than once is a recipe for bad performance.

Comment: -1 for such an ugly incorrect code ;)

Comment: What do you mean by " I need to bind a grid several times "??.Can u explain little bit more how do you want to bind the GridView2.

Comment: i want the databind to append the whole data

Comment: i want the databind to append the data into the grid like listbox where we have the appenddatabounditems(but here i am applying a template field)thanx for asking

Comment: if this was a bad code only then I am asking here :P

Comment: @To all above except amanjot singh. I know this is a dumb question but see the reputation of the guys who is asking before putting any negative votes. He might be confused but i thing instead of marking it negative we should write a small comment please be specific and suggest what you gained from the above. If your view and his matches then i think he will get his answer and he said he is "Why he is asking question on SO?" because of good repu of SO. I hope i am clear and giving him + vote.

Comment: See diago's action he edit his question and also put a comment. That's the thing i want to express. +1 to diago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your List declaration and GridView assignments to outside the for loop - right now you are creating a new List every iteration, you only want to create one, and then bind that to the Grid.. eg:

```
List<business.clspluginsprp> objprp = new List<business.clspluginsprp>();
business.clsplugins obj = new business.clsplugins();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < k.Length; i++)
{

    Int32 z = Convert.ToInt32(k.GetValue(i));
    objprp.Add(obj.fnd_plugins(z));

}

GridView2.DataSource = objprp;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: An error arrived which is as:
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<business.clspluginsprp>.Add(business.clspluginsprp)' has some invalid arguments
while the other error is :
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<business.clspluginsprp>' to 'business.clspluginsprp'

Answer (score 0):

Cou cannot bind twice. Then you call DataBind(). The Control rebuild it contents based on the current data source. Old contents are discarded. So you should use a List containg ALL your data, assign it to DataSource and then call DataBind()

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

This approach may be helpful for you.Get the concept from the code and implement in your way.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcSample" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**Code behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet dsSample = GetDataSet();
    GridView gvSample;
    if (dsSample.Tables.Count > 0 && dsSample.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int iCount = 0; iCount < dsSample.Tables.Count; iCount++)
        {
            gvSample = new GridView();
            gvSample.DataSource = dsSample.Tables[iCount];
            gvSample.DataBind();
            plcSample.Controls.Add(gvSample);
        }
    }

}

private DataSet GetDataSet()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt;

    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Code", typeof(string)));
    DataRow dr;
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = 1;
    dr["Code"] = "KK";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = 2;
    dr["Code"] = "Karan";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Code", typeof(string)));
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = 1;
    dr["Code"] = "AA";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["ID"] = 2;
    dr["Code"] = "Arun";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

    return ds;
}
```